# Повернуть Стринг Слева Направо

Tags: javascript

Ребята помогите плиз разобраться в этом коде.
Мне не совсем понятно, зачем создавать переменную text = textNode.data и в конце писать эту строку кода ещё раз, только в другом порядке textNode.data = text.
И зачем нужно использовать метода .data ?

```
function animate_string(id) 
{
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var textNode = element.childNodes[0]; // если представить что нет никаких потомков 
  var text = textNode.data;

setInterval(function () 
{
  text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
  textNode.data = text;
}, 100);
}
```

Comment: А все остальное вы хотите вам понятно, особенно про `setInterval` и модифицирование `text`?

Comment: Свойства `data` у `Node` и потомков нет. Вывод: Кто-то писал noob style. По смыслу, вроде пытается перевернуть строку, зачем-то используя свойство и задержку.

Answer (score 2):

`textNode.data = text` - здесь мы присваиваем св-ву `data` новое значение, которое получилось в результате конкатенации строк (последний символ становится первым)
Св-во `data` отвечает за непосредственное значение, которое отображется в `textNode` и поменяв его, мы поменяем текст в `textNode`

```
var text = textNode.data; // сохраняем текущий текст из textNode
...
text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1); // изменяем текст
...
textNode.data = text; // по сути меняем текст в элементе, на который ссылается textNode
```